# Need to accept Image (multipart form) as ASP.NET Web API POST and post it as BLOB Stream Byte[] to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I've looked and looked and can't figure out how to accept an image (multipart form data) via the ASP.NET Web API and then upload that image most likely as a stream / byte array to a BLOB storage service like Azure (and get it back and return that as an image).  I'm most concerned about doing the first part: getting the image and storing it as a BLOB.  If you have any code or links you can share, that would be much appreciated!!

So far this is the best thing I've found http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Uploading-large-files-386ec0af#content  ....but still working to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Yao's the guy with the answer.  Yippee, that only took FOREVER to find and resolve.  Probably 8 or more hours into this.....

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Uploading-large-files-386ec0af#content